How to make the modules of Intellij that only exist in other branches invisible when switching branches?
This problem has troubled me for a long time. As shown in the figure below, the module "crud" only exists in another branch, but when I switch branches, I can still see this folder. Is there any configuration or operation that can automatically block the non-existent module when I switch branches?

I hope someone can solve my problem

I don't think it will be something that you can do just like that because modules are written in config files... which is not something that changes when you switch branches.

Git doesn't delete anything listed in the .gitignore when switching branches. If anything inside crud is ignored, git won't delete that directory.
However, it does allow running custom code after a checkout using Hooks. You can create a post-checkout hook (located in .git/hooks/post-checkout that deletes crud if it isn't in the HEAD.
You can check whether the HEAD contains a directory using git ls-tree. Similarly, I am using this answer to not delete anything if there are untracked files in crud.
#!/bin/bash

# you can put a script like that in .git/hooks/post-checkout

if [ -z "$(git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only crud)" -a -z "$(git ls-files crud --exclude-standard --others)" ]; then
    echo "deleting crud directory"
    rm -rf crud
fi

Be careful
Note that the above hook can be dangerous. If you have any important (as in you don't want it to be deleted/isn't automatically generated) data in the crud directory that is ignored via the .gitignore, this script will delete the data.
How does the script work?
The command git ls-tree -r HEAD --name-only crud lists all files in the crud directory of the HEAD (the current branch).
Similarly, git ls-files crud --exclude-standard --others lists all untracked files in the crud directory (i.e. files you haven't checked out). See this answer for details on that.
Finally, I am using the option -z to check if the output of these commands are empty and combining these two expressions with -a which is a logical AND.
So essentially, I am only deleting the crud directory if the currently checked out ref doesn't have that directory (i.e. you checked out a branch that doesn't have crud) and you have no untracked files.
By saving it in .git/hooks/post-checkout and marking it executable, it will be executed automatically after every git checkout.
